# Kubernetes cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope even after creating rolebindings

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci

Im running a pipeline that creates a kubernetes namespace but when I run it I get:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-runner:default" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

I created a `ClusterRole` and a `ClusterRoleBinding` to allow the service user `default` in the `gitlab-runner` namespace to create namespaces with:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: modify-namespace
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - namespace
    verbs:
      - create
```

and:

```
ind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: modify-namespace-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: modify-namespace
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: gitlab-runner
```

But that gives me the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to add other `verbs` like `get` and `list` to your ClusterRole? Because probably `create` may not be enough. Permissions like `get`,`list`, watch etc can also be required because it should be controlled that the namespace you are trying to create is already exists or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [""] in clusterrole manifest it should be just `""`.
  because [""] will be array where apiGroups expects a string.
- under `resources` it should be `namespaces` not `namespace` because :

```
kubectl api-resources | grep 'namespace\|NAME'
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
namespaces                        ns           v1                                     false        Namespace
```

- so clusterrole manifest should be as following :

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: modify-namespace
rules:
  - apiGroups: ""
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - create
```

Comment: thanks i didn't know about `kubectl api-resources`. namespaces did the trick.
`[""]` however is correct, I tried otherwise and it failed because it expects an array.

Comment: I have the same error, but this solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue below:

```
Namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:openshift-operators:minio-operator" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

Got solved with below yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cluster-role-cesar-3
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - create    
---    
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-binding-cesar-3
  namespace: openshift-operators
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: minio-operator
  namespace: openshift-operators
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-role-cesar-3
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```