# How do I create a clusterrole binding that allows a service account to create namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a custom template for a coder.com installation on a self hosted kubernetes cluster.

When I try to crate a new workspace from the template, I get the following error.

```
Error: namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:coder:coder" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
on main.tf line 42, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "workspace":
  42: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "workspace" {
```

I have tried to apply the following ClusterRole and ClsuterRoleBiding, but I get the same error

```
# a cluster role that allows creating namespaces
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: coder-create-namespace
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","create","edit","delete","view"]
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: coder-create-namespace
  namespace:
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: coder-create-namespace
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: coder
  namespace: coder
---
```

This is my coder template terraform file.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    coder = {
      source  = "coder/coder"
      version = "~> 0.11.0"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "~> 2.22"
    }
  }
}

provider "coder" {
}

variable "use_kubeconfig" {
  type        = bool
  description = <<-EOF
  Use host kubeconfig? (true/false)

  Set this to false if the Coder host is itself running as a Pod on the same
  Kubernetes cluster as you are deploying workspaces to.

  Set this to true if the Coder host is running outside the Kubernetes cluster
  for workspaces.  A valid "~/.kube/config" must be present on the Coder host.
  EOF
  default     = false
}

# Info about the current workspace
data "coder_workspace" "me" {}

# Used for all resources created by this template
locals {
  name = "coder-ws-${lower(data.coder_workspace.me.owner)}-${lower(data.coder_workspace.me.name)}"
  labels = {
    "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by" = "coder"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "workspace" {
  metadata {
    name   = local.name
    labels = local.labels
  }
}
```

Comment: For cluster-wide objects like namespaces, you need to create ClusterRoleBinding instead of RoleBinding.

Answer (score 1):

[Kubernetes cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope even after creating rolebindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484413/kubernetes-cannot-create-resource-namespaces-in-api-group-at-the-cluster-sc)

You might consdier above link for your refernce issue

did you define IAMrole and policy for your cluster in your mainest file

Comment: Thanks, that question, did not directly answer my question, but it did put me in the right direction. I will update my question with a note about the correct rbac.yaml format.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution to my problem.

```
# a cluster role that allows creating namespaces
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: coder-create-namespace
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs: 
      - create
      - get
      - list
      - watch
      - delete
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: coder-create-namespace
  namespace:
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: coder-create-namespace
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: coder
  namespace: coder
---
```